# Set type of class property based on another type of the same instance

Tags: typescript

Why is the assignment to `this.propertyB` throwing a TS error here?

```js
class Example {
    public readonly propertyA: boolean;
    private readonly propertyB: this['propertyA'] extends true ? null : 'value';

    public constructor() {
        this.propertyA = true;
        this.propertyB = this.propertyA ? null : 'value'; 
                    //^ Type '"value" | null' is not assignable to type 'this["propertyA"] extends true ? null : "value"'.
                    // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'this["propertyA"] extends true ? null : "value"'.
    }
}
```

@EDIT: Tried with a class generic parameter

```js
class Example<T extends boolean> {
    public readonly propertyA: T;
    private readonly propertyB: T extends true ? null : 'value';

    public constructor(arg: T) {
        this.propertyA = arg;
        this.propertyB = this.propertyA ? null : 'value';
    }
}
```

Throws:

```
Type '"value" | null' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? null : "value"'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? null : "value"'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: The compiler can't verify it as safe. Indeed it's not safe as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/NDdYON). But even if it were, the `this` type is an implicit generic type parame, your property is a conditional type depending on it, and the compiler really can't do much analysis on such types; there's an open feature request at [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) to improve this, but it's not obvious how to do so both safely and conveniently. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Is there any way I could simulate the same behavior using a class generic type? I edited the question with my unsuccessful attempt at it... @jcalz

Comment: Is that a followup question? As I said `this` is an implicit generic type parameter ("parame" was a typo), and the same problem shows up if you use an explicit generic type parameter. It doesn't change things. I demonstrated why what you're doing is not safe (so you don't want to "simulate" it) and why, even if it were safe, you can't easily get the compiler to see it. I don't quite understand what your addendum is asking for, but note that "why is X" isn't the same question as "how do I do Y", and you should really be asking only one primary question here.  What should we do to proceed?

Comment: Yep my bad. I'll mark the question as resolved, thank you for the help!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#4910](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) is an *implicit* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the current type.  So you can think of `this` as being something like `This` in `class Example<This extends Example<This>> {⋯}`

Your `propertyB` property is therefore of a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a generic type parameter.  The type checker doesn't know what it will evaluate to until it knows what the type parameter's type argument will be.  So you can think of it as a nearly *opaque* type.  TypeScript doesn't know what values might be assignable to it, and it complains about almost anything you might try, such as `this.propertyA ? null : 'value'`.

It looks like the check of `this.propertyA` should have *some* effect on the type of `this`, but TypeScript doesn't model that.  It can't "see" that `this.propertyA ? null : "value"` resembles `this['propertyA'] extends true ? null : 'value'`.  There's a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for some better support here (that issue is specifically phrased in terms of function return types, but it's the same phenomenon).

And it's been open for this long because it's not trivial to implement.  It isn't clear when you can and can't make the assumption that the generic conditional type `T extends U ? V : W` and the result of the conditional check `isU(t) ? v : w` are safely compatible with each other.  Indeed, in your very example, the assignment is *not* safe:

```
class Example {
  public readonly propertyA: boolean;
  private readonly propertyB: this['propertyA'] extends true ? null : 'value';

  public constructor() {
    this.propertyA = true;
    this.propertyB = this.propertyA ? null : 'value';
  }
  propB() { return this.propertyB }
}

class Subclass extends Example {
  public readonly propertyA: false = false;
}
new Subclass().propB().toUpperCase(); // RUNTIME ERROR
```

Here, `Subclass` extends the `Example` class and refines its `propertyA` property type from `boolean` to `false`.  I added a `propB()` method to `Example` to allow the unsoundness to be visible.  Since `propertyA` is of type `false` in `Subclass`, the `propB()` method of an instance of `SubClass` returns type `false extends true ? null : "value"`, which is `"value"`.  Except that we have *not* made such the relevant assignment to `propertyB`.  The super constructor just makes that `null` no matter what.  And so we easily get a runtime error when trying to treat `null` as if it were `"value"`.

You can certainly rewrite your class so that such runtime errors are impossible or unlikely to occur while still using generic conditional types. But even if you do manage to make it 100% type safe, the compiler still can't see that.  So in the event that you're sure you want to proceed, you can just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you're vouching for the safety of the assignment:

```
this.propertyB = (this.propertyA ? null : 'value') as
  this['propertyA'] extends true ? null : 'value'; // no error
```

That will remove the compiler error.  Of course that means you are now responsible for the type safety here, so triple check that what you're doing is safe (to whatever degree of likelihood you care about) before making such an assertion.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNaKArgEYgCWw0ATumACYD2AdiAJ4FUMrpUAurAQQBc0YgwYYwTANx4OZAG5hemGvWZsOXHvwBCI3gAsyEANoByFJ259B5gLrR08FUzoxeVQpgD80JoQgINAi5kog3uayckSkFNDAzBCehMC8DFQAFACU2HL4RiYAdFbatgLQALzQKeiy+AXGECXWOqy6VdCZhc2lNvwVfgFBIdBhYBHo5rmQ+Q09Fn1tAg5OLuhuHl6+-oHBoeGR9dAAvjHWujl5DdTovIRUTDVNLWV6cmdnOKCQMADKJB+UDWrnccEQqAw1wIJHIlDUjBY7CW5READMJhBMNUMSAsbIzkx0AB3aAA4hAiA5V4oS7ZIrpACqKBsAGFIOgctJoAB6HnQABKjIAcgAVACSAFlYHABQKAPICoA)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Example {
    public readonly propertyA: boolean;
    private readonly propertyB: this['propertyA'] extends true ? null : 'value';

    public constructor() {
        this.propertyA = true;
        this.propertyB = this.propertyA ? null! : 'value' as this['propertyA'] extends true ? null : 'value';
    }
}
```